# Sticky UIView on top of Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm new to Swift programming, and I'm stuck with figuring out this structure.

[image]

I'm trying to make an UIView on top of the underlying ViewController even when navigating to other ViewControllers.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: will presentViewController work for you ?

Comment: You can set constrain like 10 or 15 px from bottom, it will stay on that position no matter which ever view you try...

Comment: Do you mean that you want a UIVView on a specific place for all your application, regarding of the view controller that it is showing?

Comment: @William Kinaan, yes thats what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @SiavashGoudarzi I don't know if that is possible or not. sorry ...